# nested collection_set

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm building a recurring billing system and am having trouble with a nested form. The following code works, but makes a POST with:

```
"customer"=>{"service"=>{"service_id"=>"1"}}
```

It should be Customer.services instead of Customer.service.  However, if I change the form to reference fields_for :services, it doesn't render a dropdown at all.

_form.html.haml

```
= form_for @customer do |f|
= f.fields_for :service do |service_fields|
  = service_fields.collection_select(:service_id, Service.all, :id, :name, { :prompt => 'Select Package' })
= f.submit "Add Service", class: "btn"
```

models/customer.rb

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :subscriptions, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :services, :through => :subscriptions

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :services
end
```

models/service.rb

```
class Service < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :customers, :through => :subscriptions
  has_many :subscriptions
end
```

models/subscription.rb

```
class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
  belongs_to :service
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, in this situation you want to build a `subscription` on the `customer`. Since you're pretty much on the right track, it should be as simple as changing this

**_form.html.haml**

```
= form_for @customer do |f|
= f.fields_for :subscriptions do |subscription_fields|
  = subscription_fields.collection_select(:service_id, Service.all, :id, :name, { :prompt => 'Select Package' })
= f.submit "Add Service", class: "btn"
```

**models/customer.rb**

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :subscriptions, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :services, :through => :subscriptions

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :subscriptions
end
```

Right now the reason why you're getting anything rendered is because you're causing the form to submit with a new "attribute" called `service` with then returns the data from the `fields_for`. With `accepts_nested_attributes_for {model}` you should be looking for a `params` with something like `{model}_attributes`

Also the reason why you're not getting anything rendered when you use `:services` in the `fields_for` is because `Service` doesn't respond to `service_id`.

Comment: Thanks for the help, however I'm still having a similar issue. Using the changes you posted, the form doesn't render at all. Changing it to `= f.fields_for :subscription do |subscription_fields|` renders the form properly, then on POST ends up getting `unknown attribute: subscription`.

Comment: You probably haven't build a `subscription` yet. Put `@customer.subscriptions.build` in the controller method.

Comment: I have that in the customer controller, however I have to have `f.fields_for :subscription` instead of `f.fields_for :subscriptions` for the form to render at all, which results in the unknown attribute error.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out finally (with the help of a colleague.) I made all of the above changes thanks to @Azolo's reply above with also changing the form view to:

_form.html.haml

```
= f.fields_for :subscriptions, @customer.subscriptions.build do |builder|
```